# Aspose excel autofitcolumn but for a certain width

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, aspose, aspose-cells

I want to fit column according to header width not the properties width.Ie Header size should be the column width )

i am using `sheet.AutoFitColumns();` which fits according to the max length of cell.

ie
[image: pic1]

I want to have sheet like this.(Header size should be the column width ie **3b 3c**)

[image: pic2]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That `AutFitColumns` method has an [overload](https://reference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/worksheet/autofitcolumns/#autofitcolumns_4) that allows to specify the range upon which to apply the autofit.

```
public void AutoFitColumns(int firstRow, int firstColumn, int lastRow, int lastColumn)
```

For your scenario that might be below one (indexes are 0-based) - *you might need to adjust*.

```
sheet.AutoFitColumns(2, 1, 2, 2);
```